# Select from all tables having same fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables named as: `data_yyyymmdd`.
Ex. data_20121028, data_20121029, ...

Each table have same fields. How can I get all the records from all those tables?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM data_20121028
UNION
SELECT * FROM data_20121029
UNION
...
```

[MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html): [UNION Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html)